# runtime binding and virtual inheritence

Tags: c++, inheritance

```
class Base {
  public:
  virtual int f() const {
       cout << "Base::f()\n";
       return 1;
}
 virtual void f(string) const {}
 virtual void g() const {}
};

class Derived4 : public Base {
  public:
       int f(int) const {
         cout << "Derived4::f()\n";
         return 4;
    }
};

int main()
{
    string s("hello");

    Derived4 d4;
    Base& br = d4; // Upcast
    // br.f(1); // Derived version unavailable
    br.f(); // why does it compile and run?
    br.f(s);// why does it compile and run?
}
```

In derived : overloading `f()` of base .. so all base `f()` versions should be hidden.
Now, for **br.f()** and **br.f(s)** : because of runtime binding, `f()` and `f(s)` of derived should be called, BUT they should be hidden, still the code compiles and executes int Base::f() and void Base::f(string).

**Q1 :** What am i missing?
**Q2 :** `br.f(1)` does not compile because, during compile time, type checking is performed and `int f(int)` is not present in Base. Am i correct?

Comment: You're not overloading anything in the derived class!!! The prototype of function `f` is different from any of the prototypes of function `f` in the base class. Also, it is unclear what you mean by "hidden". Functions `f()` and `f(string)` are `public` in the base class, so there shouldn't be any problem calling them with a base object.

Comment: Base ::`int f()` , Derived ::`int f(int)` , you mean this is not overloading?

Comment: They are hidden, so if you try `d4.f()` and `d4.f(s)`, it won't compile. But `br`'s type is `Base`, compiler don't and can't know its real type(`Derived4`), so `br.f()` and `br.f(s)` are OK.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't call it "hidden", it's just that your `Derived` version of `f` makes it impossible for the compiler to understand that you are trying to call `f` of the base class. Also, you're now saying that `br.f()` and `br.f(s)` are OK, so I don't really understand what your problem is.

Comment: This is not "virtual inheritance"...

Comment: If your compiler accepts C++11, try adding `override` after function declaration.  In cases where it is not considered as override, it will complain.

Comment: @barakmanos the code is able to execute `br.f()` and `br.f(s)` which should not be done, because of overloading. They should definitely compile because Br is pointer to Base class, and both `f` are present in Base.
During runtime, compiler **should fail** to execute derived::`f` because of the fact that `f` is present in Derived.

Answer (score 1):

Base class never knows about the newly added members in derived class, it has the information only about the members declared itself.
So when derive class instance `d4` is assigned to base class reference `br`, the newly added method `int f(int) const` is hidden to `br`. That’s why the compilation error for below code

```
// br.f(1); // Derived version unavailable
```

where as below two line are compiled successfully

```
br.f();
br.f(s);
```

For more understanding:

```
class Base {
  public:
  virtual int f() const {
       cout << "Base::f()\n";
       return 1;
}
 virtual void f(string) const {}
 virtual void g() const {}
};

class Derived4 : public Base {
  public:
       int f(int) const {
         cout << "Derived4::f()\n";
         return 4;
    }
    void g() const {
         cout<< "Derived4::g()" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    string s("hello");

    Derived4 d4;
    Base& br = d4; // Upcast
    // br.f(1); // Derived version unavailable
    br.f(); // No Compilation error
    br.f(s);// No Compilation error

    d4.f();  // Compilation error
    d4.f(s); // Compilation error
    d4.f(1); // No Compilation error
    d4.g();  // No Compilation error
    br.g();  // Will print - "Derived4::g()"
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The function `int Derived4::f(int)` *hides* functions from base class, but does not *override* them.  To do so, it should have had the exact same signature.

In case of function *override*, you can call the function on the base class reference and see the derived class function being called.